# Element IDs for Selenium scripts

Tags: selenium-rc

Using Selenium RC

On my web app I am trying to open windows by clicking links. These windows don't have any IDs so selenium.GetAllWindowIds() doesn't work. I've worked around this by getting their names.

Are these IDs something which the developer can insert so as to make automation less tricky?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use xpaths instead of ids.

Comment: Yes, your devs can insert IDs for _any_ element in the page.